# Find the max number in list after m operations between indices a and b

Tags: c++, comparative-review

Given the problem:

> You are provided a list of N elements all initialized to 0, and a list of M operations. Where each m in M consists of 3 elements a, b, and k. For each m in M add k to all indices in the range [a, b]. At the end of all M operations print out the max.

I have two implementations, one of which is faster because of constant time lookups, whereas the other can be more memory usage efficient. I am looking for a third implementation which might run faster than the previous two.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <climits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void run_tests1(int N, int M, const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &a_b_k)
{
    std::vector<int> LIST(N);
    int max = INT_MIN;

    for (int m = 0; m < M; ++m) {
        int a = a_b_k[m][0];
        int b = a_b_k[m][1];
        int k = a_b_k[m][2];

        clock_t now = clock();
        for (int i = a; i <= b; ++i) {
            LIST[i] += k;
            if (LIST[i] > max) {
                max = LIST[i];
            }
        }
        clock_t end = clock() - now;
        std::cout << "Took " << ((float)end / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " on "
          << __FUNCTION__ << " to insert " << (b - a + 1) << std::endl;
    }
}

void run_tests2(int /*N*/, int M, const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &a_b_k)
{
    std::map<int, int> LIST;
    int max = INT_MIN;

    for (int m = 0; m < M; ++m) {
        int a = a_b_k[m][0];
        int b = a_b_k[m][1];
        int k = a_b_k[m][2];

        clock_t now = clock();
        for (int i = a; i <= b; ++i) {
            std::pair<std::map<int, int>::iterator, bool> status =
              LIST.insert(std::make_pair(i, 0));

            status.first->second += k;
            if (status.first->second > max) {
                max = status.first->second;
            }
        }
        clock_t end = clock() - now;
        std::cout << "Took " << ((float)end / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " on "
          << __FUNCTION__ << " to insert " << (b - a + 1) << std::endl;
    }
}

void run_tests3(int N, int M, const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &a_b_k)
{
    // Choose Data Structure
    int max = INT_MIN;

    for (int m = 0; m < M; ++m) {
        int a = a_b_k[m][0];
        int b = a_b_k[m][1];
        int k = a_b_k[m][2];

        clock_t now = clock();
        // Run Algorithm
        clock_t end = clock() - now;
        std::cout << "Took " << ((float)end / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " on "
          << __FUNCTION__ << " to insert " << (b - a + 1) << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int K = 1000;
    const int N = 10000000;
    const int M = 10;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > data(M);

    for (int m = 0; m < M; ++m) {
      data[m].resize(3);
      data[m][0] = rand() % N;
      data[m][1] = rand() % N;
      data[m][2] = rand() % K;

      if (data[m][0] > data[m][1]) {
          std::swap(data[m][0], data[m][1]);
      }
    }

    run_tests1(N, M, data);
    run_tests2(N, M, data);
    run_tests3(N, M, data);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, don't ask us to write code for you. Writing the code is your responsibility; we will just critique it.

1. Why are you concerned about how long it takes to process each operation? The only thing that matters is the overall time and space requirement, and it's not a given that the best solution is going to operate by processing each operation in sequence. Thus, the timing does not belong in the loop. And I would even make the case that the timing does not belong in the `run_testsn()` functions. The timing belongs in your main function, which will call each of the `run_testsn()` in sequence. Each function should have one purpose only. It shouldn't be "Do this in this particular way and then time subunits of it.".
2. You've got a lot of unnecessary `#include`s. That just clutters up the code. Only use the ones you need.
3. Kudos to you for qualifying your C++ types with `std::`. But as @Morwenn said, don't forget to do it for functions from the C standard library too.
4. Is it necessary to take your input as a `vector` of `vector`s? It would make a lot more sense to build a `struct` with members `int a; int b; int k;` and then pass `vector`s of that around.
5. A `map` is pretty good for representing a sparse array; there are several other libraries out there that do better. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-sparse-array-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310680/sparse-array-in-c
6. You have two (soon-to-be three) functions that take the same parameter list and do the same thing. This looks like a job for an abstract base class (specifying the interface/params) and three subclasses of that class that each have implementations.
7. In `run_tests2` you have

   > ```
   >        std::pair<std::map<int, int>::iterator, bool> status =
   >          LIST.insert(std::make_pair(i, 0));
   >
   >        status.first->second += k;
   > ```

   What's wrong with `LIST[i] += k;`? If the item doesn't exist yet, it will be auto-created with the default value (0). (And even if not, please declare it using `auto status =` as that type is just plain ugly and doesn't add anything. You're using C++11, take advantage of ways it can produce better code)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the vote of confidence, but you just asked this question and it's possible, maybe even likely, that someone else might respond to it. Tradition is to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another set of small remarks to add to what @Snowbody already mentioned. I didn't see anything that seemed to be C++11-related in your code so I will explicitly mention whenever my remarks include C++11 elements:

- [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11): `__FUNCTION__` is a non-standard compiler extension. If you want to get the name of a function in a standard-compliant way, use `__func__` instead.
- @Snowbody mentioned the fact that you explicitly `std::-qualified` every member from the C++ standard library, which is great. However, you should have pushed that one step further and also `std::`-qualify the features from the C standard library such as `std::rand`, `std::clock` or `std::clock_t`.
- `INT_MIN` is the C way to get the maximum value of an `int`. The C++ way to do it is to use `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` from the header `<limits>`.
- You should try to avoid all-caps names for anything that isn't a macro. In C and C++, we generally try to use all-caps names only for macros so that people know that they are using identifiers that do not respect the usual scoping rules of C++. I understand that you used `N` and `M` since they are from the problem description, but `LIST` could have been `list` for example.
- [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11): instead of the old `<ctime>` API, you can use the new features from `<chrono>` to time your code:

  ```
  auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  // Here, include the code you want to time

  auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << "Took "
            << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end-begin).count()
            << "ms on "
            << __func__
            << " to insert "
            << (b - a + 1)
            << std::endl;
  ```

  Even if you can't use C++11, there is an equivalent library in Boost that you can use even with C++03.
- The following piece of code:

  ```
  if (LIST[i] > max) {
      max = LIST[i];
  }
  ```

  ...can be replaced by this simpler one:

  ```
  max = std::max(max, LIST[i]);
  ```
- You forgot to seed the random number generator with `std::srand`. Chances are that your random numbers will be the same from one execution to the other.
- [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11): anyway, the `std::rand` function is not the safest random function in the world. Well, to be honest it is not guaranteed to be thread-safe at all and would still be standard-compliant even if it always returned integers between 0 and 10 with a neat preference for 3 (for record, the C11 specification even includes a note about the function not being safe). You can write a simple thread-safe `randint` function with the C++11 `<random>` API:

  ```
  template<typename Integer>
  Integer randint(Integer low, Integer high)
  {
      thread_local std::random_device rd;
      thread_local std::mt19937 engine(rd());
      thread_local std::uniform_int_distribution<Integer> dist{};

      using param_type = std::uniform_int_distribution<Integer>::param_type;
      return dist(engine, param_type{low, high});
  }
  ```

  Note however that `std::random_device`, a feature that should produce non-deterministic pseudo-random numbers, is not well-implemented in every standard library. For example, MinGW's one does not produce random numbers at all. You could initialize the `std::19937` with `std::time(nullptr)` instead of `rd()` if you want to be sure.

  Alternatively, this library is also available in Boost and is known to work. So you could even use it without a C++11-compliant compiler. Your pick.